# Pulling in JSON data gives response code of 200, but content length of -1 which breaks everything

Tags: android, json, http

I am building an android app that pulls in and displays data from a JSON api.

Specifically, the JSON api that I am pulling from is [here](http://www.johncorser.com/?json=1&count=15/)

```
    URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://www.johncorser.com/?json=1&count=15/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    Log.i(TAG, "Code: " + responseCode);
    Log.i(TAG, "Length " + connection.getContentLength());
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
        char[] charArray = new char[contentLength]; //Line 97, where the error is thrown because contentLength == -1
        reader.read(charArray);
        String responseData = new String(charArray);
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseData);

    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP response code: " + responseCode);
    }
```

When I run this, the logcat gives me this stacktrace:

```
10-15 11:36:00.512    8704-8718/com.johncorser.johncorser I/MainListActivity﹕ Code: 200
10-15 11:36:00.512    8704-8718/com.johncorser.johncorser I/MainListActivity﹕ Length -1
10-15 11:36:00.512    8704-8718/com.johncorser.johncorser E/MainListActivity﹕ Exception caught:
    java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
            at com.johncorser.johncorser.MainListActivity$GetBlogPostTask.doInBackground(MainListActivity.java:97)
            at com.johncorser.johncorser.MainListActivity$GetBlogPostTask.doInBackground(MainListActivity.java:80)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The strangest part is, if I swap the api with one structured in a nearly identical way, like the one [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=15), the code executes without errors.

Any idea why I can't load this specific JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that service returns data in chunks (`Transfer-Encoding:chunked` in response headers), so it does not know content-length at the time it sends headers.

To handle such situation you can just wrap your `InputStreamReader` in `BufferedReader` and read it line by line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String chunk;
while ((chunk = br.readLine()) != null) {
    responseBuilder.append(chunk);
}            

String responseData = responseBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: This solved it quickly and easily, and explained the mistake I made in a very straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

If the content length isn't known when the server sends the headers, then it doesn't tell the client the length; that means that the client doesn't know the length, and the call returns -1. Details are [in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) for `URLConnection`.

What this means in practical terms is that you can't do it with a fixed length char array. You have to read the response line by line, into a `StringBuilder`, until you've exhausted the input. Then you can put the result into your `JSONObject` constructor.

Remember that some things on the web stream live content, so it's impossible for them to know the total length at the point when they start transmitting. That means you can't ever rely on being told the length; and because of that, some things are lazy and don't bother telling you the length even when they do know it.

Here are the headers your `johncorser.com` web site returns for that page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Oct 2014 15:40:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=82ivean17opsfkqjf9n4itdog2; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://www.johncorser.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Note there's nothing about length there. But the `teamtreehouse.com` site you also linked to, with a similar structure, returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 15 Oct 2014 15:46:59 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4422
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Pingback: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Cacheable: SHORT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Cache-Control: max-age=600, must-revalidate
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache: HIT: 2
X-Cache-Group: normal
X-Type: default
```

Note that this one includes a `Content-Length: 4422`.

Answer (score 1):

See the api description: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()
"Returns the content length in bytes specified by the response header field content-length or -1 if this field is not set."

The http response is not sending content length header back